# Azure Data Factory - Execute SSIS Package with Package Parameters

Tags: parameters, ssis, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to execute a SSIS package with parameters in Azure Data Factory v2 using the "Execute SSIS Package" activity.

However I get the following error:

```
Activity Execute SSIS Package failed: Failed get parameter info of parameter JobID.
```

Pipeline set up like so:

```
{
"name": "Master Load",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Execute SSIS Package",
            "type": "ExecuteSSISPackage",
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false
            },
            "typeProperties": {
                "packageLocation": {
                    "packagePath": "blah/blah/blah.dtsx"
                },
                "loggingLevel": "Basic",
                "environmentPath": "blah/blah",
                "connectVia": {
                    "referenceName": "blah-SSISIR",
                    "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                },
                "packageParameters": {
                    "JobID": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.JobID"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "JobID": {
            "type": "Int",
            "defaultValue": -1
        }
    },
    "folder": {
        "name": "Master Loads"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"}
```

JobID is a Project parameter in the SSIS project I have. SSIS 2016 and we deploy the package to ADFv2/Azure/whatever you want to call it.

The package runs successfully without the packageParameters section and just uses the default values in the package but we want to set these at runtime.

Anyone come across this or have any examples to share?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You state that JobID is a project parameter, then you should use `projectParameters` rather than `packageParameters` in your json